# Program that will calculate denominations of coins of a given amount of change

Tags: c++

I am supposed to create a (one function) program that will calculate denominations of coins of a given amount of change.

Somehow I am not getting the number of dimes/quarters etc to display out correctly, it just gives me 00000. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int DOLLAR = 100;
const int QUARTER = 25;
const int DIME = 10;
const int NICKEL = 5;
const int PENNY = 1;

void getChange (double &money, int &value);
int change(double &money, int value);

int main()
{
    double money;
    int value;

    getChange (money, value);


    int numDollar = change(money, DOLLAR);

    int numQuarter = change(money, QUARTER);

    int numDime = change(money, DIME);

    int numNickel = change(money, NICKEL);

    int numPenny = change(money, PENNY);


    cout << numDollar << endl;
    cout << numQuarter <<endl;
    cout << numDime <<endl;
    cout << numNickel <<endl;
    cout << numPenny <<endl;
    cout << value <<endl;



}

void getChange (double &money, int &value)
{
    cin >> money;
    value = static_cast<double>(money) * 100;

}


int change(double &money, int value)
{
    int numDollar, numQuarter, numDime, numNickel, numPenny;

    while(value>100)
        numDollar = value / DOLLAR;
    money = value - (numDollar*DOLLAR);

    numQuarter = money / QUARTER;
    money = money - (numQuarter*QUARTER);

    numDime = money / DIME;
    money = money - (numDime*DIME);

    numNickel = money / NICKEL;
    money = money - (numNickel*NICKEL);

    numPenny = money / PENNY;
    money = money - (numPenny*PENNY);

    return money;

}
```

Comment: First, you need to understand what you are trying to do. (Even that part is already confused. You can't seem to keep track of whether the `money` variable is in dollars or cents.) Once you know what you're doing, step through the code in the debugger and check that each step results in what you expect.

Comment: This question should be posted to codereview or programming stackexchange.

Comment: Focus on the `change` function until you understand why it always returns 0. Then write a new `change` function that works like your `main` assumes. (Hint: `change` should be completely unaware of the denominations.)

Comment: thank you guys, i am trying to understand what went wrong, i suppose there has to be a single equation in the while loop instead of all the int variables...

Answer (score 0):

Try stepping through your program and you'll notice that `change()` is always returning `0`, so the output is correct, but the function obviously is not.

Think about what the function returns and what it's supposed to return. Also keep in mind that you're passing a reference, so whatever you do to `money` within `change()` will  persist even outside the function's scope.

Since you'll want `change()` to return the number of coins, you'd most likely want it to return the amount of money divided by the value of the current coin.

---

***Don't read past the this line unless you're really stuck, but even then try to figure it out yourself first!*** If you can't, read on step by step, then think about it again, etc.

Let's have a quick look at your implementation of `change()`:

```
while(value>100)
    numDollar = value / DOLLAR;
```

This doesn't make a lot of sense here. `value` will hold the worth of the current coin, yet you're somehow trying to do some calculation with it. Since `value` doesn't change inside this loop, you essentially created an infinite loop. It isn't entered, since `value` is never bigger than `100` right now (since `DOLLAR` (`100`) is the biggest value passed).

numQuarter = money / QUARTER;
   money = money - (numQuarter*QUARTER);

This will correctly calculate the numbers of quarters and calculate the remainder. However, this is not what you're supposed to do here, since the actual coin `value` is meant to be determined by the parameter.

Last, but not least, you've got your return statement:

```
return money;
```

If everything is working as expected (assuming the current implementation would be expected; i.e. calculate all coin counts), then the money now is supposed to be `0`, which is returned.

---

A big part of "programming" is actually about being able to take some idea and then translate it into some code structure. It's not about knowing all possible functions in some namespace or header file (you can always look those up). It's about being able to write down concepts and ideas and understanding them, if written by someone else. If you want, use the following code for inspiration, but really don't continue unless you really understand what each single line does.

---

Here's my quick and dirty solution. There's no error handling and such, but it seems to work properly:

```
#include <iostream>

const unsigned int DOLLAR  = 100;
const unsigned int QUARTER =  25;
const unsigned int DIME    =  10;
const unsigned int NICKEL  =   5;
const unsigned int PENNY   =   1;

unsigned int change(unsigned int &money, unsigned int coin);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    double input;

    // Retrieve the amount of money from the user.
    std::cout << "Enter the amount in USD: ";
    std::cin >> input;    

    // Now convert it into cents for processing.
    unsigned int money = input * 100;

    // And now count and output the number of coins:
    std::cout << "You'll get:\n";
    std::cout << "\t" << change(money, DOLLAR) << " dollar(s)\n";
    std::cout << "\t" << change(money, QUARTER) << " quarter(s)\n";
    std::cout << "\t" << change(money, DIME) << " dime(s)\n";
    std::cout << "\t" << change(money, NICKEL) << " nickel(s)\n";
    std::cout << "\t" << change(money, PENNY) << " penny(s)" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

unsigned int change(unsigned int &money, unsigned int coin) {
    // First count the number of coins that fit into the amount.
    // Since we're doing integer division, all results will be rounded down.
    const unsigned int count = money / coin;
    // Then calculate the remainder and update it.
    // The modulo operator (%) always returns the integer remainder.
    money %= coin;
    // Return the number of coins of this size
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you Mario for the advice, what I will focus on now is to focus on my change() function, I even drew the whole structure on paper and am currently to figure it out... I guess my mistake was to jump into coding quickly.. I am still learning but I am sure when I get used to coding, I will understand a lil more. Btw I am a applied physics major trying to understand CS... apparently everything I know in physics is wayyy different in CS, I am struggling with this course to be honest :(

Comment: Don't worry. The basic idea behind your `change()` implementation is correct (except the loop). You just put everything into the function rather than the repeating pattern only.